# Insert Yii module string in URL using mod_rewrite for mobile browser

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, yii

I want to rewrite URL to access Yii module when a mobile browser detected. In Yii, I make a new module called `mobile`. I don't use theming (which is the common method for mobile site) since I intent to implement quite different logics for normal browser and mobile browser user.

The `mobile` module will be accessed using `http://localhost/project/mobile` (or `http://project/mobile` in production).

The default `.htaccess` file for Yii is below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/
#RewriteBase / #for production

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The problem is I want to insert string `mobile` for every URL accessed by mobile browser.
for example

```
http://localhost/project/user -> http://localhost/project/mobile/user
http://localhost/project/login -> http://localhost/project/mobile/login
http://localhost/project/books/1 -> http://localhost/project/mobile/books/1
```

or for production.

```
http://project/user -> http://project/mobile/user
http://project/login -> http://project/mobile/login
http://project/books/1 -> http://project/mobile/books/1
```

Anyone knows what the new `.htaccess` for this will be?

I don't mind changing few variables for development and production server and for the mobile browser detection I guess I can use the rule from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

# Redirect /project/*/ to /project/mobile/*/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera|mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/mobile/$1 [L,R]

# Forward request to Yii
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It was adapted from `.htaccess` showed in here http://ohryan.ca/blog/2011/01/21/modern-mobile-redirect-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do here is group all mobile functionality under a "mobile" module, and use Yii's PreRouter functionality to redirect the user in Yii itself. This gives you a lot more control about everything.

```
class PreRouter
{ 
    public function routeRequest($oEvent)
    {
       $oApp = $oEvent->sender;
       if (<isMobile>)
          $oApp->defaultModule = 'mobile';
    }
}
```

In your config you add:

```
'onbeginRequest' => array('PreRouter', 'routeRequest'),
```

Under the main array (so NOT under modules, it's an app setting).

As said, this gives you a lot of control over everything. You can determine when the user is to be redirected (for example iPad is also a mobile but a lot of people want the regular site). With this method you can store for example in a cookie that they want to remain on normal site instead of mobile etc.

I know its not with rewrites as you requested but I still hope you find the answer usefull :)

Comment: Actually right now I prefer the rewrites since it's simpler. But nevertheless, your answer is great. Anyway, can I override URL rules using this method?

Comment: You should be able to, although I haven't tried. The onBeginRequest is the very first thing that is done, even before the processRequest in the WebApplication. Since it only does the url parsing in processRequest it should not be a problem.